# accessing instance list of class

Tags: java, list, class, arraylist

I am new to Java and I have a question about how to access instance list of class in detail. (I really need your help!)

Let's say we have pairs of numbers such as (1 2), (3 4), (5 6), (5 3), (1 5).
And for each pair, we consider the first one as head and the last one as tail (eg 1->head and 2->tail). Every time we get a pair or node from input, we will store the pair into a Nodelist.

Here is the question I would like to ask.
Is there any other ways to access only heads from the Nodelist?? For example, consider the last node, which has this pair(1 5). We will call 1 as a lastnode.head and 5 as a lastnode.tail.
What I want to do now is to check whether the lastnode.head(1) is in the Nodelist. In the Nodelist, we already have (1 2) node. Then we store (1 2) into some DS. After that, in this time, we check lastnode.tail(5) in the Nodelist. Notice that we have two pairs (5 6) and (5 3) and when we check, we only consider heads in the Nodelist. Since (5 6) comes first than (5 3), we store (5 6) and then (5 3) in sequence.

Any suggestions or ideas on this question?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have some kind of pair class, let's say like this:

```
class MyPair {
    public int head, tail;
    
    public MyPair(int head, int tail) {
        this.head = head;
        this.tail = tail;
    }

    ...
}
```

Very standard approach would be using for loop and compare variable of each pair based on what you are looking for. For example, let's say, you have created an ArrayList filled with some elements:

```
List<MyPair> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(new MyPair(1, 2));
myList.add(new MyPair(3, 4));
...
```

then, you can use for loop for example like this:

```
boolean containsHead(List<MyPair> list, int value) {
    for(MyPair pair : list) {
        if(pair.head == value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

usage:

```
containsHead(myList, 3);
>> true
```

you could do very simiar method for tails.

Another approach would be to change your structure, for example instead of using list of pairs you could use "pair of lists" - create 2 lists, like this:

```
List<Integer>
    heads = new ArrayList<>(),
    tails = new ArrayList<>();

heads.add(1);
tails.add(2);
...
```

usage:

```
tails.contains(2);
>> true
```

One last approach I thought of, however I would not recommend using, is overriding equals method, making your class behave as either of items you set it to.

```
class MyPair {
    public int head, tail;
    
    public MyPair(int head, int tail) {
        this.head = head;
        this.tail = tail;
    }
    
    private static boolean asHead = true;
    
    public static MyPair searchOf(int x) {
        return new MyPair(x, x);
    }
    
    public static void behaveAsHead() {
        asHead = true;
    }
    
    public static void behaveAsTail() {
        asHead = false;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other instanceof MyPair) {
            MyPair otherPair = (MyPair) other;
            return asHead ? (head == otherPair.head) : (tail == otherPair.tail);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
// search for tail of value 4
MyPair.behaveAsTail();
myList.contains(MyPair.searchOf(4));
>> true
```